# Are tangent vectors independent of choice of chart? (Example case)

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

In the definition of (how to construct) a tangent vector with respect to a given manifold $M$, at a particular point $x \in M$, [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_as_velocities_of_curves) as equivalence class of certain curves through $x$, it is explicitly noted (where I added emphasis to the quote):

> The tangent space of $M$ at $x$ [...] is defined as the set of all tangent vectors [at $x$];
>   it **does not depend on the choice of chart** [...]

I'd like to understand whether and why such independence holds specificly for the following example choices of [charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)#Charts) of a suitable open subset $U$ of a given [2-dimensional manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-manifold) $M$:

Consider

- $\varphi : U \longleftrightarrow \{ \, (a, b) \in \mathbb R^2 \, | \, (-1 \lt a \lt 1) \text{  and  } (a - 1 \lt b \lt 1 - a) \, \}$
  explicitly being a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) from $U$ (wrt. its topology given by 2-dimensional manifold $M$ as a [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space)) to the described open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ (wrt. its [usual topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space#Topological_properties));
  and having an inverse, $\varphi^{-1}$, which is a homeomorphism as well);
  therefore $(U, \varphi)$ explicitly being a chart, where explicitly $x \equiv \varphi^{-1}[ \, (0, 0) \, ] \in U$,

and

- function $f : \mathbb R^2 \longleftrightarrow \mathbb R^2, \qquad f[ \, (a, b) \, ] \mapsto (p, q) \equiv (a + $[$\text{Abs}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value)$[ \, b \, ] ,b) $.

**My questions:**

(1) Is it correct that function $f$ is a homeomorphism (wrt. usual topology) ?

(2) Is it correct that $\psi : U \longleftrightarrow \{ \, (p, q) \in \mathbb R^2 \, | \, (-1 \lt p \lt 1) \text{  and  } (-1 - p \lt q \lt 1 + p) \, \}, \qquad \psi \equiv f \circ \varphi, $
is a homeomorphism as well; and that consequently $(U, \psi)$ is a chart, too ?

Further, returning to the [definition of tangent vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_as_velocities_of_curves) referenced above:

(3) Does the curve $\gamma : (-1, 1) \to M, \qquad \gamma[ \, t \, ] \mapsto \varphi^{-1}[ \, (0, t) \, ],$
belong to an equivalence class of curves which constitutes a tangent vector on $M$ in point $x \equiv \varphi^{-1}[ \, (0, 0) \, ]$ ?,

and

(4) Does the curve $\rho : (-1, 1) \to M, \qquad \rho[ \, \tau \, ] \mapsto \psi^{-1}[ \, (0, \tau) \, ],$
belong to an equivalence class of curves which constitutes a tangent vector on $M$ in point $x \equiv \psi^{-1}[ \, (0, 0) \, ] = \varphi^{-1}[ \, (0, 0) \, ]$ ?

---

Here's an illustration of the two curves $\gamma$ and $\rho$, projected into the ranges of chart $(U, \varphi)$, and of chart $(U, \psi)$, respectively:

[image: The ranges of both charts, together with projections of both curves. MSE/q/2285719]